# No route found for "GET /api" - NotFoundHttpException - ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: api, symfony, routes

I'm currently working on a Symfony 3.3 project and I'm using different bundles:

- FOSRestBundle
- NelmioCorsBundle
- JMSSerealizerBundle
- LexikJWWTAuthenticationBundle

I want to create a Symfony API to Angular, but I have the following problem:

[image: This page]

My routing.yml (#app/config/routing.yml) :

[image: routing.yml]

Can you help me, please?

good day :)

Comment: I'm in localhost

Comment: You can use `php bin/console debug:route` to print all routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is absolutelly expected, as you do not have any controller, configured for path "/api".

You need to create a Controller, with path under "/api", for example, "/api/users" and then it will work.

"/api" is just a prefix for your API, so all your API URLs will start from it, but it does not mean that /api itself should work.

Comment: Thank you, I have almost the same error with login_check --'